# Placing sticky images on top of each other

Tags: html, css, animation

**Goal**:

When scrolling down through a website, an image will follow along and change depending on how far you have scrolled.

**My Plan**:

Place images on top of each other and let them be sticky. Run animation depending on scroll position.

**My Problem:**

I have **three** images that I needs to be sticky. However, they also need to be absolute to be placed on top of each other, which is obviously contradictory. Am I approaching the problem from the wrong direction?

Don't think too much about the animation stuff, I will figure that out. For now I just need help placing images on top of each other while also being sticky.

**Current code:** https://codepen.io/alsb/pen/oNwZYQw

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello to Sticky World</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        Numquam et blanditiis repellendus voluptas iusto recusandae quis 
        quos iure quod eos possimus ad corrupti, nam asperiores, 
        minima quisquam praesentium neque ratione?
    </p>
    <div class="container">
        <img class="item" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
        <img class="item" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
        <img class="item" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
    </div>

    <p>...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
.sticky-container {
    height: 100%;
}

img.sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
    border: 2px dashed rgba(114, 186, 94, 0.35);
    height: 400px;
    background: rgba(114, 186, 94, 0.05);
  }
  
  .item {
    position: sticky;
    top: 1rem;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to not use `<img>`. The inner-most div will be sticky, wrapped in an absolute div.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 50vw;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
    border: 2px dashed rgba(114, 186, 94, 0.35);
    height: 900px;
    background: rgba(114, 186, 94, 0.05);
  }
  
  .item {
    position: sticky;
    top: 1rem;
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/500/300");
  }
```